# How this Null exception possible. Need help interpreting call stack

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, nullpointerexception

In my REST WCF service I log all exceptions on WCF stack level (`IErrorHandler`)

Here is my code:

```
public void PostPositions(List<Position> positions)
{
    if (!this.ValidateRequest()) return;
    foreach (var position in positions)
    {
```

I get exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at Web.Services.MobileService.PostPositions(List`1 positions)
>   in
>   C:\CodeWorkspace\ClientServerCode\Web.Services\Rest\MobileService.cs:line
>   1170         at SyncInvokePostPositions(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)

Line 1170 in my code is for `if (!this.ValidateRequest()) return;`

What does it mean? There is no static methods, I work with instance of a class and `this` definitely exists. If exception happens inside `ValidateRequest()` I expect stack trace to show that.

Any pointers?

Comment: Sometimes line numbers can be slightly off.  Set a breakpoint there, and see if anything else is null -- for example, `positions`.

Comment: Not knowing the code of ValidateRequest(), then the only other point of possible error is if `positions == null`

Comment: @KirkWoll I can't reproduce this, this is in production environment. In my experience line numbers matching good for this one..

Comment: Then add logging.  *Obviously* `this` is not null, so move on to the next possibility.  *Especially* in production, line numbers can be off in stack traces.

Comment: @Steve ValidateRequest() has bunch of code, but line numbers in 2000+ - I think it should point to that area if it was inside ValidateRequest. I tend to think also it's `positions` but so far I never had mismatchning line numbers

Comment: I concur with the observations of @KirkWoll, I usually don't take that lines number as absolute truth. If you could reproduce the error in production then add some kind of logging to exclude the error inside ValidateRequest().

Comment: Technically, with some delegate trickery, you _can_ make `this` null: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951624/how-to-create-a-delegate-to-an-instance-method-with-a-null-target though I sincerely doubt this is happening here.

Comment: When I was working with WCF earlier, I found WCF did some voodoo with raised exceptions (because of WCF's own built-in exception handling support as part of its Faults vs. Errors design). The best thing is to inner-wrap your method with its own try/catch/finally and see what happens. Besides that, the obvious problem is your PDB files are out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be willing to bet that `positions` is what's null and that `foreach(var position in positions)` is what's throwing the exception when calling `GetEnumerator()` on positions.

```
if(positions != null)
{
    foreach(var position in positions)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

As you might guess, it'd be very easy for the line number calculation to get a bit jumbled here, since the `foreach` loop is just syntactic sugar for something like this:

```
IEnumerator<Position> enumerator = positions.GetEnumerator();

try
{
    Position position;

    while(enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        position = enumerator.Current;

        //The code from the body of your foreach loop goes here
    }
 }
 finally
 {
     //Clean up the enumerator
 }
```