# GetValue from list of GetProperties without an instantiated object using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, getproperties

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public IBy Some1{ get { return By.CssSelector("span[id$=spanEarth]"); } }

    public IBy Some2 { get { return By.CssSelector("span[id$=spanWorm]"); } }

    public IBy Some3 { get { return By.CssSelector("span[id$=spanJim]"); } }
}
```

is the class, and I am using reflection in this fashion:

```
var gridRow = Type.GetType(typeof(SomeOtherClassInSameNamespace).AssemblyQualifiedName.Replace("SomeOtherClassInSameNamespace", "SomeClass"), true, true);

var rowList = gridRow.GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.Name.Contains("IBy")).ToList();

int i = 0;
foreach (var property in rowList)
{
    string test = property.GetValue(gridRow, null).ToString();
}
```

Which gives a runtime error for an objectType exception. How do I get the values from the list of properties using Reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gridRow` is a reference to a `Type` object. The first parameter of [`GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx) is meant to be the target object - so it's like you're trying to access the `SomeClass` properties on a `Type` object. That's clearly not going to work.

While there *are* [hacky ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11162876/22656) of evaluating an instance property without having a reference to an instance - so long as the property doesn't use `this` - they really are pretty nasty.

If a property doesn't need any state within an object, make it a static property instead. At that point you can use `null` as the target, and it'll be fine:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public static IBy Some1 { get { return By.CssSelector("span[id$=spanEarth]"); } }

    public static IBy Some2 { get { return By.CssSelector("span[id$=spanWorm]"); } }

    public static IBy Some3 { get { return By.CssSelector("span[id$=spanJim]"); } }
}
...

var gridRow = Type.GetType(typeof(SomeOtherClassInSameNamespace)
                              .AssemblyQualifiedName
                              .Replace("SomeOtherClassInSameNamespace", "SomeClass"),
                           true, true);
var rowList = gridRow.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                     .Where(p => p.PropertyType.Name.Contains("IBy"));

int i = 0;
foreach (var property in rowList)
{
    string test = property.GetValue(null, null).ToString();
    ...
}
```