# Check if a lazy singleton was ever created

Tags: c#, ninject

Using ninject, I have a binding like this:

```
kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<MyFoo>().InSingletonScope()
    .WithConstructorArgument("bar", new Action<IFoo>(foo =>
    {
        // some function here
    }));
```

What I want to be able to do is determine whether or not `IFoo` was constructed without actually trying to use it (since that would cause it to be constructed). Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: you can try [this mildly hilarious answer from Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162652/c-sharp-get-property-value-without-creating-instance)

Comment: @Jonesy: That's not quite the same thing. I want the kernel to tell me if it constructed an instance of `IFoo`. That's not trying to access an instance member without an instance.

Comment: Why is it important for you to check whether the instance is created or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `OnActivation(...)` - which takes an `Action` as parameter - to the binding. With this you can do whatever you want, including setting a flag to true.

For example:

```
static bool fooWasCreated = false;

kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<MyFoo>()
      .InSingletonScope()
      .OnActivation(fooInstance => fooWasCreated = true);
```

there's also an overload available where you get access to `IContext`. Also it's not necessary to use a static variable, as an alternative you can also access another component which was bound `InSingletonScope()`

Comment: I like this answer because I can still defer to ninject to figure out what other dependencies `MyFoo` might need injected.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a matter of applying the right patterns, such as the proxy pattern:

```
public class LazyFooProxy : IFoo
{
    private readonly Lazy<IFoo> foo;
    public LazyFooProxy(Lazy<IFoo> foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public bool IsCreated {
        get { return this.foo.IsValueCreated; }
    }

    void IFoo.Method() {
        this.foo.Value.Method();
    }
}
```

Here we created a `LazyFooProxy` proxy class that is able to delay the creation of `IFoo` and it also allows checking whether the foo has been created (by calling the `Lazy<T>.IsValueCreated` property).

Now you can make the following registration:

```
var lazyFoo = new LazyFooProxy(new Lazy<IFoo>(kernel.Get<MyFoo>));
kernel.Bind<IFoo>().ToInstance(lazyFoo);
kernel.Bind<MyFoo>().InSingletonScope();
```

Now you can use the `LazyFooProxy.IsCreated` property to check whether `MyFoo` was created or not.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, if you poke around through Ninject's internals enough, that you could find a way to look for the existence of objects that would only be there after this binding has been invoked. But it's easier to just set up your binding to a factory method that sets a flag you can check.

```
kernel.Bind<IFoo>().ToMethod(
    kernel => {
        Tracker.FooIsInitialized = true;
        return new MyFoo(kernel.Get<IDependency>());
    })
    .InSingletonScope()
    .WithConstructorArgument("bar", new Action<IFoo>(foo =>
    {
        // some function here
    }));
```

Comment: For me this seems to be the best answer

Comment: I guess the one downside here is that I now have to explicitly add all the dependencies of `MyFoo` myself instead of letting ninject figure it out itself.

Comment: @MattBurland: That's true. The accepted answer is definitely better.

Answer (score 0):

When constructed have it trigger a Boolean that you can check for true/false and just get that value

Comment: That is possible *in this case*, but seems a little janky. I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't rely on the specifics of *how* the object was constructed. If `IFoo` was bound to some other implementation, I'd like to still be able to detect that an instance of `IFoo` was constructed.

Answer (score 0):

### Generally

This may seem to be offtopic but you may find several useful implementations of singleton, by Jon Skeet [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx).

### Question

If I understood it correctly you simply need to add a `bool` Property indicating whether the instance has been created or not. eg:

```
public static bool IsCreated { get { return _instance != null; } }
```

How ever this is beeing used, it should be made threadsave..

### Implementing a Wrapper

```
public static class FooWrapper 
{
    public static bool IsCreated { get; private set; } // default false

    public static IFoo GetInstance()
    {
        IsCreated = true;

        // return the Singleton Instance of IFoo
    }
}
```

Make sure the only way accessing your `IFoo` Instance is with `FooWrapper.GetInstance()`

Comment: As per my comment to @Vermonster's answer, this kind of solution requires knowing something about the implementation of `IFoo`. I'm looking for a solution that would work regardless of the implementation of `IFoo`.

Comment: @matt burland either the Interface implements this property or you need to wrap the whole interface in a new singleton class. Ensure all your classes access this class. This might work.

Comment: An interface can't have a static property.

Comment: Whups... sorry named it wrong.. its not an interface