# C#: OOP inheritance of property

Tags: c#, oop

I want to inherit that a class has a property, but different implementations of this class will have different values for this property and the property should be available without instantiating an object.
Eg: every animal has a value numberOfLegs. For every cat it is 4 for every snake it is 0. Now I want to loop through some   animal Types and print out how many legs that animal subclass has without creating an instance of that class.

Comment: Static properties do not participate in inheritance.

Comment: check out this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162652/c-sharp-get-property-value-without-creating-instance

Comment: "I want to loop through ... without creating an instance of that class" is not a real requirement.

Comment: If the number of legs can change from one animal to another, then that attribute isn't static, because it can change.

Answer (score 1):

You could give a chance to the following:

First declare your Animal abstract base class which will be responsible for storing types and numberoflegs

```
abstract class Animal
    {
        protected readonly static IDictionary<Type, int> _legsDictionary = new Dictionary<Type, int>();
    }
```

And an Animal abstract class which has the static property NumberOfLegs:

```
abstract class Animal<T> :Animal where T : class
    {
        public static int NumberOfLegs
        {
            get => _legsDictionary.ContainsKey(typeof(T)) ? _legsDictionary[typeof(T)] : -1;
            set
            {
                _legsDictionary[typeof(T)] = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

And then just declare as many Animals as you want >>>

```
class Cat : Animal<Cat> { }
class Snake : Animal<Snake> { }
class Human : Animal<Human> { }
```

And testing:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Cat.NumberOfLegs = 4;
            Snake.NumberOfLegs = 0;
            Human.NumberOfLegs = 2;

            Console.WriteLine(Cat.NumberOfLegs);
            Console.WriteLine(Snake.NumberOfLegs);
            Console.WriteLine(Human.NumberOfLegs);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: This meets the constraint of what was asked but would you ever want to use something like this?

Comment: I must be honest and I will never use something like this =). I am just answering what he asked. I think that if he wanted to ask about its architecture or design then he would have posted (maybe in meta) a question for that.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want to achieve isn't possible in the way you want it to be.

The `static` keyword stays persistent between every class.
What you can do is the following:

```
class Animal
{
    public static int LegCount { get { return 0; } }
}

class Snake : Animal
{
    public static new int LegCount { get { return 0; } }
}

class Human : Animal
{
    public static new int LegCount { get { return 2; } }
}

class Cat : Animal
{
    public static new int LegCount { get { return 4; } }
}
```

With the `new` keyword you can make each new type return a different value.

But note that a `List<Animal>` will always always return `0`, since the `new` only hides within the type and is not the same as an `override`.

Comment: Adding `new` before a member only suppresses a warning, the fact that this is a very wrong design doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could also define your interface requirement (having a `numberOfLegs` property) by implementing an interface instead of inheriting from a base class. That way, you can place the static values at the levels of abstraction where they don't change across instances:

```
interface IAnimal
{
    int numberOfLegs { get; }
}

class Snake : IAnimal
{
    public static int numberOfLegs = 0;

    int IAnimal.numberOfLegs
    {
        get { return numberOfLegs; }
    }
}

class Cat: IAnimal
{
    public static int numberOfLegs = 4;

    int IAnimal.numberOfLegs
    {
        get { return numberOfLegs; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The interface won't work on the types, you still need instance to use this. Side note, with `=>` you only need half the lines.

Comment: Well, the requirement of having a static property that can change as well as enumerating different types of animals without instantiating classes of animals is messy. To be honest, if I arrived to a similar situation myself, I might go back to the drawing board. Thanks for the hints!